# How i show image src on click

Tags: javascript, image, this, src, confirm

Write a function that will be called upon pressing the right button of one of the images you have on the site.
The function calls up a confirm () window in which you ask the user if he wants to know the source of the image
If the user clicks OK alert (this.src), which shows the content of the src attribute of that image
If the user clicks on cancel, disable the context menu that appears at
pressing the right button

this is my wrong code

```html
<img src="opera1.png" id="immagine1" alt="immagine1" width="500" height="333" oncontextmenu="destra()">
<img src="ioaparatissima.JPG" id="immagine2" alt="immagine2" width="500" height="333" oncontextmenu="destra()">
```

javascript

```
function destra(){
  var r = confirm("Vuoi conoscere la src dell'immagine");

  if(r == true) {
    alert(y.src);
  } else {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved like this

```js
function destra(y) {

    window.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){e.preventDefault();}, false);

    var r = confirm("do you want to know the src of the image?");

  if(r == true) {
    alert(y.src);
  } else {

  }

}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="immagine1"id="immagine1" alt="immagine1" width="150" height="150" oncontextmenu="destra(this)">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="immagine2" id="immagine2" alt="immagine2" width="150" height="150" oncontextmenu="destra(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using inline event bindings I would suggest two changes.

`oncontextmenu="destra(this)"`

Pass in the element that the inline event binding is on.

```
function destra(y){
  var r = confirm("Vuoi conoscere la src dell'immagine");

  if(r == true) {
    alert(y.src);
  } else {
  }
}
```

Accept the element as a method argument.

Answer (score 0):

By rereading your statement it seems to me that this answer corresponds better ... (?)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(el=> el.addEventListener('contextmenu',destra) )
 
function destra(e)
  {
  e.preventDefault() // disable real context Menu

  if ( confirm("Vuoi conoscere la src dell'immagine") )
    {
    alert( this.src )
    }
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="immagine1" >

<img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="immagine2" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getElementById()`, like in this example:

```
function destra() {
    let r = confirm("Vuoi conoscere la src dell'immagine?");
    let y = document.getElementById("immagine1");
    if (r == true) {
        alert(y.src);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this... I hope this one usefull...

```
<img src="opera1.png" id="img1" alt="immagine1" width="500" height="333">
<button onclick="getimgId(1)">copy link</button>
<br/>
<img src="ioaparatissima.JPG" id="img2" alt="immagine2" width="500" height="333">
<button onclick="getimgId(2)">copy link</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getimgId(img_id){
        var res = confirm("Vuoi conoscere la src dell'immagine");

        if(res == true) {
            var img_id = img_id;
            var img_url = document.getElementById('img'+img_id).src;
            alert(img_url);
        } else {

        }
    }
</script>
```

now you want to just give unique id to images and there right side buttons of images...

like img1, img2, img3 for images and onclick="getimg(1)", getimg(2), getimg(3)...

you can easily assign unique ids using Javascript. just apply loop and inside the loops add imgs with unique ids...

for assign unique I share example below...below code is just for Your Reference. do changes as per your needs. you can search on google for more examples.

```
for(var i=0;i<yourRecordArray.length;i++){
    newList = document.createElement('li');
    newList.className = 'list-border';
    newList.id = 'imgdiv'+i;
    newList.innerHTML = '<img src="" id="img'+i+'">+
                        '<button onclick="">';
    document.getElementById('add').appendChild(newList);
```